# Powershell IIS .Net Authorization Rules Roles

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-8

I am trying to get the roles for the authorization rules when I click on the server and not the site.

this is what I am using

```
Get-WebConfiguration /system.webServer/security/authorization/ -Location IIS:\
```

but whatever I try I can't get the roles that are listed. Using gm it gives me nothing I can use. I have searched online and everyone has a way to set the data but not get the data.

Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authorization/ I can't figure out how to get the roles. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found it. I was looking in the wrong section.

```
Get-WebConfiguration /system.web/authorization/ -Location IIS:\
```

is where you want to look. Look under collection from there and you will see all the roles.

Comment: The code above doesn't run, not sure what your output was supposed to be, but maybe something like below would get everything exposed
Get-WebConfiguration /system.web/authorization -Location IIS:\ | Select *